# How to use Domainatrix.parse("STRING").host from a string instead of static url

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I want to use this line of code in Ruby:

```
Domainatrix.parse("String").host
```

On the "String" place, I want to use a string which contains multiple links. 
When I insert my string on that place, i get error about he doesn't know .parse.
When I insert a static url, it works.

But how can I use my string in it to parse multiple links?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
urls.map do |url|
  result <<  Domainatrix.parse(url).host 
end
```

Comment: If this doesn't work could you give a sample of the string? Commas are not supported in URLs as far as I know  so you may need to `urls.split(',').map do ...`